# Response is different on local and EC2 server

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, django-rest-framework, request, localhost

I have an API that would return a list of user with custom field.
The data in the database of EC2 is the same as local database. However, when I tried to posting a request, the response is different between localhost and server.
I got 420 rows from local, but only got 415 rows from server. (420 is expected)

Since data in the database is the same, I don't know how to figure out this problems.

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

serializer_class = serializers.UserSerializer
queryset = models.User.objects.all()
permission_classes = [NotAuthReadOnly]
filter_class = UserFilter

def get_queryset(self):
    return self.queryset.is_active()

@action(methods=['get'], detail=False)
def for_custom_field(self, request, **kwargs):
    serializer = serializers.ForSelectField(self.queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

class ForSelectField(serializers.Serializer):
id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
name = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
full_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

def get_full_name(self, instance):
    return instance.name + ' ' \
           + instance.user_code + '  ' \
           + str(instance.customer_set.filter_active().count())
```

Comment: Hi Anna, welcome to stackoverflow. Unfortunately it is almost impossible to answer your question without seeing code/example of data. Would you mind editing your question and adding these details?

Comment: How do you know the data is the same when the same query returns different results?? Either the data is not the same or the query is incorrect.

Comment: I dump the database on server and just import it to the local database.
And the API of user list "without custom field" is the same on local and server.

Comment: with so few rows it may be useful to dump both results into excel and side by side match them to identify the missing rows and give a clue as to why.